# When do derivatives cancel inside integrals when working with tensors?

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, tensors, index-notation

While doing a problem recently I realised I'm not clear about when derivatives inside integrals will cancel when working with tensors.

For example, I have come across integrals such as:

$\int \partial^\mu \varphi_\nu \ \mathrm{d}^4 x$

$\int \partial^\mu \varphi_\mu \ \mathrm{d}^4 x$

$\int \partial^\nu \varphi^\mu \partial_\nu \varphi_\mu \ \mathrm{d}^4 x$

$\int \partial^\mu \varphi^\nu \partial_\nu \varphi_\mu \ \mathrm{d}^4 x$

In many of these problems I initially suspected that the derivatives inside the integrals should cancel. However the more I thought about it, the more I convinced myself they wouldn't. For instance in the first integral, it seems like you would end up with:

$\int \partial^\mu \varphi_\nu \ \mathrm{d}^4 x=\int \varphi \ \mathrm{d}^3 x $

because only one integral cancels with the single, given derivative.

Similar reasoning made me think none of them cancel. However I then realised I'm not sure in what situation such cancellation WOULD occur.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain, with an example, when this cancellation does occur.

Comment: The fields are assumed to vanish at infinity, therefore any divergence yields zero. Any derivative that you can get rid of by an integration yields zero.  The first two integrals are thus zero. In general, you are allowed to perform  a partial integration by moving derivatives acting on one part of the expression to all other parts, as the derivative acting on all parts yields zero.

Comment: @CountIblis Could you perhaps add an answer and expand a bit more on what you've said here with some working? I don't see how assuming the fields vanish at infinite means the divergence is zero?

Comment: While it is true that I have encountered all of these integrals in field theory, I am also interested in when derivative/integral cancellation for tensor expressions can happen in general too. Any answer addressing this would be great!